# Permutation Algorithm in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, permutation

I read this permutation function example in a Haskell textbook and I was wondering if someone could help me understand what is happening. Also, assume that the function *delete* simply deletes the first occurrence of a value from a list and returns the list

```
perms [] = [[]]
perms p = [x:xs | x <-p, xs <- perms (delete x p)]
```

I understand that an empty list equals a list with an empty list. For all other cases the head of the list is prepended to x and the numbers except the head recurses through the algorithm.

My question is how does this work, for example, my pseudocode understanding is

```
perms[1,2,3]
x <- 1
xs <- [2,3]
perms [2,3]
x <- 2
xs <- 3
perms [3]
x <- 3
xs <- []
```

this would produce the list [1,2,3] how does the algorithm produce the other list results.

An output of this code working is as follows:

```
>perms [1,2,3]
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```

Comment: No, `p` is not the head of the list. You might want to re-read the chapter about list permutations. `<-` means "for all values in".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression:

```
[x:xs | x <- p, xs <- perms (delete x p)]
```

is a list comprehension, which means that each of the `a <- b` expressions on the right hand side form a sort of implicit loop that your pseudocode doesn't account for.

Written in pseudocode with explicit loops, it's equivalent to:

```
for each x in p:
  for each xs in perms (delete x p):
    yield (x:xs)
-- and return the list of all results yielded
```

It can then be helpful to think through the definition recursively from the bottom up.  If you run `perm [n]` for any `n`, then the outer loop is only evaluated for `x = n`, and since:

```
perms (delete n [n]) = perms [] = [[]]
```

the inner loop is equivalent to:

```
for each xs in [[]]
  ...
```

and is only evaluated for `xs = []`.  Therefore, only one value is yielded:

```
x:xs = n:[] = [n]
```

So, `perm [n]` gives a list of the single element `[n]`, in other words `[[n]]`.

If you move on to `perm [1,2]` and imagine unfolding the loops:

```
-- for each x in [1,2]
first, for x = 1
  -- for each xs in perms (delete 1 [1,2]) = perms [2] = [[2]]
  so only for xs = [2]
    yield (x:xs) = yield (1:[2]) = yield [1,2]
second, for x = 2
  -- for each xs in perms (delete 2 [1,2]) = perms [1] = [[1]]
  so only for xs = [1]
    yield (x:xs) = yield (2:[1]) = yield [2,1]
```

so two values are yielded, namely `[1,2]` and `[2,1]`, giving:

```
perm [1,2] = [[1,2],[2,1]]
```

This obviously generalizes to any `perm [a,b] = [[a,b],[b,a]]`, so we can finally calculate `perm [1,2,3]`:

```
-- for each x in [1,2,3]
first, for x = 1
  -- for each xs in perms (delete 1 [1,2,3]) = perms [2,3] = [[2,3],[3,2]]
  first for xs = [2,3]
    yield (x:xs) = yield (1:[2,3]) = yield [1,2,3]
  second for xs = [3,2]
    yield (x:xs) = yield [1,3,2]
second, for x = 2
  -- for each xs in perms (delete 2 [1,2,3]) = [[1,3],[3,1]]
  first for xs = [1,3]
    yield (x:xs) = yield [2,1,3]
  second for xs = [3,1]
    yield (x:xs) = yield [2,3,1]
third, for x = 3
  first for xs = [1,2]
    yield [3,1,2]
  second for xs = [2,1]
    yield [3,2,1]
```

In all, six values are yielded, giving the list:

```
perms [1,2,3] = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```